# Decimal Format?

Tags: java, decimalformat

I just wrote a lab that is supposed to flip two coins 500 times and count how many times heads and tails were flipped and is supposed to calculate the percentage to the tenth. I remember the template for Decimal formatting, but forgot how to use it. Can somebody help? My program is as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Lab97a
{
        public static void main(String [] args)
        {


        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        DecimalFormat accuracy=new DecimalFormat("0.0");

        Dice coin;
        int numCoin;
        int numHeads;
        int numTails;
        int count;
        double percentageHeads;
        double percentageTails;

        coin=new Dice(2);
        numHeads=0;
        numTails=0;

        System.out.println("A coin is tossed 500 times. The results are asfollows: ");

        for (count=1;count<=500;count=count+1)
        {
            numCoin=coin.roll();
            if (numCoin==1)
            {
                numHeads+=1;
            }
            if (numCoin==2)
            {
                numTails+=1;
            }
        }
        percentageHeads=numHeads/5;
        percentageTails=numTails/5;
        System.out.println("Heads was flipped "+numHeads+" times,
"+percentageHeads+"%.");
        System.out.println("Tails was flipped "+numTails+" times, "+percentageTails+"%");
        }
}
```

Comment: Here's a tip: Next time, ask your actual question instead of the unrelated stuff about coin flipping. For example, "How do I print a floating point number with one decimal digit of precision? Here's the code I have already but would like to change the formatting: [short code snippet here, maybe 5 lines]". Shorter questions get better answers.

Comment: @Greg Thanks for the tip. I'll keep that in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just need to format the accuracy with e.g. `accuracy.format(percentageHeads)`. See [`NumberFormat.format(double)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#format%28double%29) that [`DecimalFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) extends.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the String.format method for this, as [described here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html):

```
   System.out.println(String.format("Heads was flipped %d times, %.2f %%"), numHeads,percentageHeads);
```